# Ordenar un array en un implode

Tags: php

Tengo un array con nombres, deseo unirlo con implode, pero al ordenarlo con asort por orden alfabetico me da error. Como se realizaría esto ?

```
<?php
$nombres = array('Pepe','Encarna','Maria','Sara','Alvaro','Manolo');
$ordenar = asort($nombres);

$unir = implode(" , ", $ordenar);

echo $unir;

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La función [`asort()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.asort.php) ordena el arreglo que recibe por referencia y devuelve verdadero si se pudo ordenar o falso si no.

```
$nombres = array('Pepe','Encarna','Maria','Sara','Alvaro','Manolo');
$ordenar = asort($nombres);
var_dump($ordenar); // Resultado: C:\ruta\archivo.php:4:boolean true
```

Entonces, debes usar el mismo arreglo ya ordenado para unir:

```
$unir = implode(" , ", $nombres);
echo $unir; // Resultado: Alvaro , Encarna , Manolo , Maria , Pepe , Sara
```

Comment: Que hace var_dump ?  es la primera vez que lo veo, como puedo evitar que me salga un texto que pongo bool(true) ?

Comment: `var_dump()` muestra el valor de una variable u objeto, es muy útil para depurar. Una vez que resuelves el problema es necesario quitar esa línea.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! por aclararme no tenia ni idea